# Batch file to copy and rename .pdf files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a set of files, generated daily, called e.g.

```
01234fileA.pdf
01234SecondFile.pdf
01234Final.pdf
```

that I need to copy to a separate directory. The numbers at the front of the file name indicate the run number producing the files, and so will A) match one another and B) always be five characters. Then I need to map the remainder of the file names to static, but different, file names:

```
fileA.pdf -> A_File.pdf
SecondFile.pdf -> File_Number_Two.pdf
Final.pdf -> Grand_Finale.pdf
```

I'm thinking that I want a for loop to cruise through the .pdf files in the folder and select the max of the leading numbers. Then I would want to take the remainder of the file name and individually map each (there are only six) to its destination. Seems like a simple enough batch process but I am hung up.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: its unclear, what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: Set source and destination directories (can be same...)
SET sourcedir=c:\sourcedir
SET destdir=c:\destdir
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.pdf" ') DO CALL :moveme "%%i"
GOTO :EOF

:moveme
SET destd=%~1
SET destf=%destd:~5%
SET destd=%destd:~0,5%
IF /i "%destf%"=="filea.pdf" SET destf=A_File.pdf
IF /i "%destf%"=="Secondfile.pdf" SET destf=File_Number_Two.pdf
IF /i "%destf%"=="Final.pdf" SET destf=Grand_Finale.pdf
ECHO MD "%destdir%\%destd%" 2>NUL
ECHO COPY /B "%sourcedir%\%~1" "%destdir%\%destd%\%destf%"
GOTO :eof
```

This should do what you've asked. All you need do is alter the source directory setting and the destination directory (which would be the parent of the subdirectories to be created)

Each filename matching the mask is processed by the `:moveme` routine. This sets the destination filename `destf` to all-but-the-first-5 characters, and directory to the first 5 characters of the name supplied.

Since you say there is a restricted list of name-transformations you want, all you need to do is follow the bouncing ball for the remaining three. The `/i` makes the comparison case-insensitive.

Finally, the directory is created - the `2>nul` will suppress the 'directory already exists' message, and the file copied to the new name.

Note that these last two operations are merely `ECHO`ed to the console - you'd need to remove the `ECHO` keyword after you've verified that the command works correctly.

It may be a good idea to add `>nul` (note : `>nul`, not `2>nul`) to the end of the `COPY` command. `>nul` here suppresses the '1 file copied' message; `2>nul` would suppress any error messages...

And the `moveme` routine was so named because I subconciously expected to `MOVE` rather than `COPY` the files. `COPY /B` would make a `COPY` of the file (duh) but leave the original in the source directory. Replaceing `COPY /B` with `MOVE` would transfer the file from source to the destination.